# Using OAuth with Scribe-Java and Google Apps

Tags: java, gwt, oauth, google-apps

I'm trying to get a list of all contacts within my Google Apps domain.

To do so I'm using the Scribe-Java library (http://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) within my GWT application.

```
String resp= "";
OAuthService service= new ServiceBuilder ()
  .provider (GoogleApi.class).apiKey ("my-domain.com").apiSecret ("my-secret").scope (
    "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/my-domain.com/full")
  .build ();
Token requestToken= service.getRequestToken ();
resp= requestToken.getToken ();
```

This code however generates the following error:

```
org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Could not find request token or secret in response: signature_invalid
base_string:POST&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2FOAuthGetRequestToken&oauth_callback%3Doob%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dmy-domain.com%26oauth_nonce%3D-714356546%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1288255870%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26scope%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252Fm8%252Ffeeds%252Fprofiles%252Fdomain%252Fmy-domain.com%252Ffull
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I got the apiKey and apiSecret from the Settings-page of my Google Apps domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a bug in Scribe.

Have a look over here for the issue:

https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/issues#issue/33

Answer (score 1):

My GWT GData OAuth Demo: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/wiki/DemoGwtGData